# Change Product Category Title from H2 to paragraph

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to change the product sub-category title from H2 to paragraph, All Sub-Categories are according to their parents https://sjcomputers.us/refurbished-laptops/ subcategories are below popular options and I want to change these titles into paragraph. The code I am using is given below:

please help me what I am doing wrong?

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_category_title','woocommerce-loop-category__title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_category_title', 'ChangeCategoryTitle', 10 );
function ChangeCategoryTitle() {
echo '<p class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the actions in one function like so

```
function yoursite_change_title_to_paragraph(){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_category_title','woocommerce-loop-category__title');
  add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_category_title', 'ChangeCategoryTitle', 10 );
}
add_action('init', 'yoursite_change_title_to_paragraph');

function ChangeCategoryTitle() {
echo '<p class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">' . esc_html_e(get_the_title()) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I tried but still the result is same.

Comment: i can't try the code because i don't have WordPress and woo-commerce set up on my computer...give me your email i can help you

Comment: ihtishamali64@gmail.com @jozek